# There was a issue when i use a admob id on 2 android app

Tags: android, admob

I've published a app whose name is "A" with `admob` id "ad_A".

Then, I added "ad_A" to another app which name is "B". But advertising appearing on B only  and does not appear on A.

I've changed `admob` id on B with another `admob` id, but A isn't appearing.

### How can I make to show ad on A again?

Edit:
I just received one email with the following contents:
Hello,
This email is to alert you that one of your applications is not currently in compliance with our AdMob program policies and as a result, ad serving has been disabled to your application.

Issue ID#:

Ad serving has been disabled to:

Action required: Check all other remaining applications in your account for compliance.

Current account status: Active

What do i do now? Help me.

I've changed admob_id on app B.

Comment: Delete Project A ID from ADMob and Create a New AdMob Id and Apply that to Project A

Comment: Can i change id of admob on B?

Comment: you can delete that Project from AdMob Account and Create a new Project  then you will get a new AdId.. add that to your project and publish your app on play store..

Comment: I try both suggest, but not working
Log: Failed to load ad: 3

Comment: it will take some time to reflect and send ads to your device and check AdId are live or not.... or try to  use Testing Ads from Admob to crosscheck your code

Comment: I find in Log Cat "No fill from ad server.". be error by ad server?!

Answer (score 0):

`NO_FILL` is returned from `AdMob` when there is no inventory left to serve in the `AdMob`/DFP backend.

First of all this meant I was requesting an ad of `size AxB`, but the backend had no ads of this size left to show. It is important that the size you request has inventory left in the backend systems of `AdMob`/DFP.

Second, their API states that the first time you request an ad to a specific ad unit, you should expect up to two minutes before the ads start serving. I don't know if it is because I am not stationed in the US, but these two minutes often becomes at least 20 minutes if not several hours for me.

Comment: So, ad is appearing soon?